# Error using IBM WAS ConnectionFactory and Spring

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms, ibm-was

I am trying to do a simple WAS/Spring/JMS application. I am grabbing the connection factory and the destination for JMS from WAS using JNDI. I am trying to use these objects with Spring JMS but I can't seem to get the casting correct. I have tried casting the connection factory to `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` and `javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory`. Should I be using some type of Spring connection factory? Any help is appreciated. WAS 8.5 and Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE.

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jndiConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jms/qcfBindingsXa");
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setLookupOnStartup(true);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setCache(true);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.class);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (ConnectionFactory) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
}


@Bean
public Destination destination() throws NamingException {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jms/app/insertQ");
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setLookupOnStartup(true);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setCache(true);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(javax.jms.Destination.class);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (Destination) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainter() throws NamingException{
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainter = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    messageListenerContainter.setDestination(destination());
    messageListenerContainter.setConnectionFactory(jndiConnectionFactory());
    //messageListenerContainter.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    messageListenerContainter.setMessageListener(messageListener());
    messageListenerContainter.setSessionTransacted(true);
    messageListenerContainter.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver());
    messageListenerContainter.afterPropertiesSet();
    return messageListenerContainter;
}
```

Error:

```
2016-02-12 09:51:03,493 ERROR o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue:///APP.INPUT.OC' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method [public abstract javax.jms.Connection javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.createConnection() throws javax.jms.JMSException] on target 
[com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle@18fbbd2_   
managed connection factory = com.ibm.ejs.jms.WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory@c51fdbc4_ 
connection manager = com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager@199d9f8f_    
restricted methods enabled = false]; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class +[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Man do I feel stupid. :/ Had the `javax.jms` jar both on the server class path as well as the application class path. Spring was looking at the application jar and WAS was looking at the server jar. I do not control or can see what is on the Server class path so I didn't realize the duplication. Thanks to everyone who at least read the question.

Comment: Hi... Can you please tell me how you fixed the issue?